# Getting incorrect output for my charAt funciton

Tags: java, arrays, charat

I have this function, and for some reason even though str =30, and i=0, str.charAt(i) gives me 51.

```java
private static void handleArmstrong(int parameter) {
    int number;
    for (number = 0; number < parameter+1; number++) {
        String str= Integer.toString(number);
        int len=str.length();
        double result=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            int base= str.charAt(0);
            result=+Math.pow(base,len);
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, because 51 is the UTF-16 code unit for '3'. (So no, you're not getting incorrect output - you just have incorrect expectations.)

Comment: So how do I get 3?

Comment: Well you could use `Character.digit`... but it's not really clear what your goal is in the first place. If you're trying to parse a string as an integer, there are already other ways of doing that. (But you're converting a number into the string to start with... it's all *really* confusing, because you haven't explained what you're trying to do.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an `int` instead of a `char` because you are implicitly converting the char into an int in this line:

```
int base= str.charAt(i);
```

You can convert the character to a number like this:

```
int base= Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i,i+1));
```

This will throw an exception if the substring is not a number so you'll need to handle that.

Comment: Im getting: Cannot resolve method 'parseString' in 'Integer'

Comment: sorry corrected it now to parseInt()